# Inserted videos don't play in PowerPoint for Mac after file has been closed and reopened

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, office-for-mac

I can successfully load a video clip into a PowerPoint slide, but after I save, close and reopen the file, only the opening image of the video appears with no way to play it.

The Play/pause bar disappears as well.

I was told to trash the appropriate PowerPoint template and reopen the program, but I'm not sure which file to trash and where it sits.

Comment: Which version of PowerPoint exactly? Which template are you even using? One you designed yourself? Can you reproduce this with any video or any template?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but i've just come across this issue and have resolved it. It also appears on top of the Google search, so i thought i'd post the concrete solution so that everyone can fix this.

I've just rectified this issue and the problem simply lies in the fact that the old PowerPoint format seems to do this without any prompt or reason why; a bug. However the new PowerPoint format fixes this.

Simply do the following:

1. Remove the video from the slide.
2. Save the PowerPoint presentation in the new ".pptx" format. Not ".ppt".
3. Ensure that the video is in the same folder/directory as the new PowerPoint (.pptx) file, just in case.
4. Open the new PowerPoint document and import the video into the slide.
5. Save and quit just to test it. Then re-open the document and you will notice that the video and it's playback controls remain there working as it should.

Hope this solved your issue ^v^